# passed prop not recognized as string

Tags: javascript

Passing a prop from a component to a modal window. The prop (radio) is received ok but when trying to use it for a switch in a function, it is not recognised. It returns an error "bannerImage" not found. But when I simply type the word "radio" into calling function, the switch  works and returns expected "bannerImage".

Since entering "radio" in the function arg works, I decided to console log the prop to see what it is returning. It is returning the word radio without quotes. So I tried to first convert the prop to a string using string template `'${prop}'` and it console logged correctly to 'radio'.  But still getting error that bannerImage not found telling me that the function arg is not been formed correctly or transmitted correctly even though it displayed it correctly as 'radio'. Confused that typing in 'radio' as func arg worked but replacing the arg with equivalent string from the converted prop ('radio') doesn't work.

```
 getHeaderImage = (modalType) => {
    switch (modalType) {
      case "radio":
        bannerImage = require('../../assets/images/weaa.png')
      break;
      default:
        // bannerImage = require('../../assets/images/weaa.png')
    }
    return bannerImage;
  }

 const { showModal, url, title, headerBgColor, modalType } = this.props;
    const iconId = `"${modalType}"`;
    bannerImage = this.getHeaderImage("radio");
    // bannerImage = this.getHeaderImage(iconId);
    console.log(modalType);
    console.log(iconId);
```

On calling the func in the render() section, it should return bannerImage for display per the switch case.  Rather I am getting bannerImage not found unless I hardcode 'radio' in the calling function which is actually the same thing as the passed prop formatted into a string.  Not sure why the passed prop is not working (see commented code for iconId).  Thanks for your help and insights.

Comment: iconId is a string with the value "radio"?

Comment: check if `modalType` is indeed a string by `console.log(typeof modalType)`

Comment: Yes modalType is indeed a string (radio) as confirmed with console.log (typeof modalType) .  However since getHeaderImage("radio") is the only way the function works, I reformatted modalType prop with `"${modalType}"` to get "radio" and still no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `switch` in different way

```
getHeaderImage = (modalType) => {
    switch (true) {
      case modalType=="radio":
        bannerImage = require('../../assets/images/weaa.png')
      break;
      default:
        // bannerImage = require('../../assets/images/weaa.png')
    }
    return bannerImage;
}
```

UPDATE

The second problem is in extra quotes in iconId - change it to

```
const iconId = `${modalType}`;
```

```js
let modalType="radio";
const iconId = `"${modalType}"`;

if(iconId != "radio") 
  console.log(`Paradox? iconId=${iconId}, modalType=${modalType}`);
```

Comment: modalType is a string as confirmed with console.log(typeof modalType). With that said, the switch format suggested won't work as it is checking on a boolean argument for modalType? What am I doing wrong?  Please help and thanks

Comment: Tried the suggested modification on the switch, but same error, can't find bannerImage.  But it works if I hardcode "radio" into the function call.  Not sure why the passed prop modalType ( a string) is not working; even when formatted again as a string to have the exact form of "radio".  I have come to my wits end and need your help. Thx

Comment: I thought the suggestion solved the problem but it didn't.  I forgot to comment out the hardcoded line that made it work.  The suggestion to remove the single quote from iconId doesn't work and still trying everything I can think of, but no cigar yet. Please don't give up in helping me on this one.  Thanks